# Typescript Definitions from Node Modules

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to configure typescript with my `tsconfig.json` so it does find definitions inside node_modules.

Ive read that it should work if i set the module to commonjs despite excluding node_modules.

I tried to remove the exclude. Tried to include manually but nothing works.

How to configure typescript to find definition files installed with the source npm package?

Comment: It should find the libraries inside the `node_modules` directory, you can read about it in the [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) part of the docs. But that doesn't mean that the definitions are there as well.. Have you installed the definitions somehow (typings, @types, etc)?

Comment: Installed definitions work, that's right. But some modules deliver the definition besides as part of the implementation

Comment: What error are you getting for the modules that come with definition files?

Comment: Also, what version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: Iam using typescript 2 and the error is simply that the import statement does not find the module

Answer (score 1):

**Typescript@2.0 (Recommended)**

You may use npm install. Example:

```
npm install --save @types/<your package name>
```

**Typescript@1.x**
Use tsd package: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd

I also have node.js + typescript@2.0 + mongodb + passportjs example right there: https://github.com/thanhtruong0315/typescript-express-passportjs.